# WPF GridLength in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, gridlength

I'm trying to define a common Width resource in Common.xaml which will be shared by different controls, like following:

```
<GridLength x:Key="CommonWidth">20</GridLength>
```

I then use it in a Button style defined in ButtonStyle.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{DynamicResource CommonWidth}"/>
    ....
</Style>
```

Common.xaml is included before ButtonStyle.xaml in the ResourceDictionary definition in App.xaml. When I ran the application (on .Net3.5 SP1), I got the following exception:

```
'20' is not a valid value for property 'Width'.
```

Anyone has any ideas of what I have done wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `Button.Width` is not of type `GridLength`. In `Grid.GridLength` you can specify the value as fixed, auto or star. It is only used for size of rows, columns in `Grid`.

`Button.Width` is of type `double`. That is if you want to set it using a resource you need a resource like

```
<sys:Double x:Key="Height">200</sys:Double>
```

Answer (score 0):

For any of the control, having width of type double you can assign the value via StaticResource as below:

Namespace to include in your xaml file:

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
```

Defining height and width as resources:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <system:Double x:Key="ControlWidth">200</system:Double>
    <system:Double x:Key="ControlHeight">20</system:Double>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Assigning value to a control:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Width="{StaticResource ControlWidth}" Height="{StaticResource ControlHeight}"/>
```